# Custom content view with Label-Entry duplicates Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, custom-controls

I have custom content view with a `Label` as title and another `Label` as detail and an edit `Icon` ; when the icon is clicked detail label is converted to `Entry` to make changes and the changes are carried over to binding.

I have bound multiple of these custom views to different properties of same object and trying to edit each one and move to next one, the problem is it seems to duplicate the individual views

I have also put `x:Name` but still it duplicates same value to the views above it ..

[image: Image1]

**Just the edit of Lastname**

[image: Edit of last name]

Now if I move to 3rd view and edit it , it replicates new value to all previously edited values. - for lastname in this case which is weird considering its not same view used in the page and on debug it hits the method only once.

[image: Issue image]

**Custom content view**:

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"
                     VerticalOptions="Start"
                     Padding="25,10,25,10">
            <StackLayout x:Name="stackLayoutDetail"
                         HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <Label x:Name="title"
                       Text="{Binding Title}" />
                <Label x:Name="detail"
                       Text="{Binding Detail}"
                       FontSize="Large"
                       FontAttributes="Bold" />
            </StackLayout>
            <Image x:Name="editIcon"
                   Source="edit_icon.png"
                   WidthRequest="25"
                   HeightRequest="25"
                   IsVisible="{Binding EditIconVisible}">
                <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="EditIcon_Clicked" />
                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
            </Image>
        </StackLayout>
```

**Code behind:**

```
private static Entry newEntry = new Entry();

public static readonly BindableProperty DetailProperty = BindableProperty.Create(propertyName: nameof(Detail),
                                                                                            returnType: typeof(string),
                                                                                            declaringType: typeof(LabelledEntrywithIcon),
                                                                                            defaultValue: default(string));


        public string Detail
        {
            get
            {
                return (string)GetValue(DetailProperty);

            }
            set => SetValue(DetailProperty, value);
        }
```

---

```
private void EditIcon_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            detailLabel = (Label)stackLayoutDetail.Children[1];
            stackLayoutDetail.Children.RemoveAt(1);
            newEntry.Text = Detail;
            stackLayoutDetail.Children.Add(newEntry);
            editIcon.IsVisible = false;
            newEntry.Completed += NewEntry_Completed;

        }


        private void NewEntry_Completed(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                var _newText = newEntry.Text;
                detailLabel.Text = _newText;
                stackLayoutDetail.Children.RemoveAt(1);
                stackLayoutDetail.Children.Add(detailLabel);
                Detail = _newText;
                editIcon.IsVisible = true;
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {

                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

**Page**

```
<local:LabelledEntrywithIcon x:Name="firstName"
                                     Title="First Name"
                                     Detail="{Binding Fella.FirstName}" />
        <local:LabelledEntrywithIcon  x:Name="lastname"
                                      Title="Last Name"
                                     Detail="{Binding Fella.LastName}" />
        <local:LabelledEntrywithIcon  x:Name="gender"
                                      Title="Gender"
                                     Detail="{Binding Fella.Gender}" />
```

Code behind:

```
ViewModel=new MainViewModel();
BindingContext = ViewModel;
```

Complete code to test is at Github repo : https://github.com/pmahend1/CustomViewDuplicationIssue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange but I changed a line of code and it works as expected now.

On the class variables changed `private static Entry newEntry= new Entry();` to 
`private static Entry newEntry;`

in `EditIcon_Clicked` method instead of `newEntry.Text = Detail;` used

`newEntry = new Entry { Text = Detail };`

I am not sure why it was taking same reference even though its new Entry for each `LabelledEntrywithIcon`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a new entry and finding and removing the label and adding the new entry after, you could simplify your problem by:

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"
                 VerticalOptions="Start"
                 Padding="25,10,25,10">
        <StackLayout x:Name="stackLayoutDetail"
                     HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Label x:Name="title"
                   Text="{Binding Title}" />
            <Label x:Name="detail"
                   Text="{Binding Detail}"
                   IsVisible="{Binding ShowLabel}"
                   FontSize="Large"
                   FontAttributes="Bold" />
             <Entry ... IsVisible="{Binding ShowEntry}" ... />
        </StackLayout>
        <Image x:Name="editIcon"
               Source="edit_icon.png"
               WidthRequest="25"
               HeightRequest="25"
               IsVisible="{Binding ShowLabel}">
            <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="EditIcon_Clicked" />
            </Image.GestureRecognizers>
        </Image>
    </StackLayout>
```

Note that I intentionally wrote ... inside the entry element as Placeholder for all customizations you might want do there (font size, etc...).

Now you add two BindablyProperties (type bool) ShowEntry and ShowLabel, where ShowLabel defaults to true and ShowEntry defaults to false.
Now all you have to do is to adapt your EditIcon_Clicked Event:

```
    private void EditIcon_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        ShowLabel = false;
        ShowEntry = true;
        newEntry.Text = Detail;
        newEntry.Completed += NewEntry_Completed;

    }
```

And adapt NewEntry_Completed to

```
    private void NewEntry_Completed(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var _newText = newEntry.Text;
            detailLabel.Text = _newText;
            ShowLabel = true;
            ShowEntry = false;
            Detail = _newText;
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {

            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Basically this does the same as your solution, however you save yourself from having to push UI Items around in your codebehind and especially the bugs and errors coming with it.

Comment: Thanks! However, this creates empty space at the place of 2nd `Label` i.e `detail` Remember we are only making it `Visible="false"` but the space it occupies , so its necessary to remove to have good UI.

Comment: Try binding the "IsEnabled" property to ShowLabel/ShowEntry as well. If it still takes up space after that, replace the StackLayout with a grid that has it's rowdefinitions set to Auto height.

Comment: I dont think IsEnabled =false will remove it, will try. I found the solution , it was simple making `newEntry` to `non- static`